# How to use orWhere when i have an array and other fields with only one value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to make filter. In view i have two inputs like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test{{$index}}" value="{{$prop_category}}"  name="prop_category[]"/>

  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-on{{ $index }}" value="{{ $prop_type }}" class="singleChb" name="publishing_types" @if ($index == 1) {!! "checked" !!}
```

In first input can have multiple values(array) and in second can have only only one value.

Now in controller i have this:

```
  foreach($options as $key => $option) {
            if($key != "search" &&
                $key != "page"  &&
                $key != "starterResult"  &&
                $key != "totalResult") {

                $query->whereHas($key,function($q) use($option){
                    $q->orWhere('name', 'like', $option);
                });
            }
        }
```

In `$options` i get an array for first input and for second i get one value. How can i use that now `orWhere` to check all of that selected values from first input. Now im able to check only for one value from first input and one from second, and not for array of first input. Any suggetion? In key i have relationships.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a given value exists in a array, you can use the method `whereIn()`:

```
$options = $request->get('prop_category');
$keys = array_keys($options);

foreach($keys as $key){

   $query->whereHas($key, function($query) use ($options) {

      $query->whereIn('name', $options);

   });

}
```

`whereIn` will check if the value from the 'name' column exists in the `$options` array.

Query builder where methods reference: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses